# Distinct instances of dataclass

Tags: python, class, init, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to create distinct instances of dataclass?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.time = datetime.now()

a1 = A().time
sleep(1)
a2 = A().time
assert a1 != a2
```

The above works fine. Let's now try the same with dataclass.

```
@dataclass
class B:
    time = datetime.now()


b1 = B().time
sleep(1)
b2 = B().time
assert b1 != b2  # does not work
```

The benefit is avoiding sugary `self` but is it at the cost of creating class specific attributes instead of instance attributes via `init`?

Maybe dataclass should be used only when one instance is possible?

Comment: Actually waiting `1` second wouldn't be necessary because `datetime.now()` gives information precise to the microsecond which is `1e-6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataclass` is a class decorator that modifies the decorated class after it's been defined. Since `datetime.now()` is evaluated and assigned to the `time` class attribute at the time of the class definition, it is too late for the `dataclass` decorator to wrap the expression into an `__init__` method as the expression has already been evaluated into a fixed value.

Instead, the `dataclasses` module offers a [`field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) method with a `default_factory` parameter to produce value for an attribute at runtime during the call to `__init__`, so that your code can work as intended as follows:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime

@dataclass
class B:
    time: datetime = field(default_factory=datetime.now)

b1 = B().time
b2 = B().time
assert b1 != b2
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/DrearySecondaryBrowsers

Comment: Thanks for nice solution. Unfortunately, it does not work when time is a string called later on in class. I stringify time, reference it with other attributes as well as in `__post_init__`.

Comment: To add more detail, I save timestamp as string, derive some folder names in another attribute and create the folder in `__post__init__`.

Comment: One way could be to move folder definition to `__post_init__`? But that removes the benefit of getting rid of self.

Comment: Can you update your question with code that demonstrates the actual problem you're trying to solve? Your description above is a bit confusing to me.